# No Signal for VGA/HDMI on new computer

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

So I ordered a new computer from CyberPowerPC and it just arrived. On my old desktop, I recall that the VGA output did not give a signal when I plugged it into my monitor; rather, with searching, I ordered a DVI male to VGA female converter. Using that with my VGA to VGA worked perfectly.

But now, I'm faced with that problem again. "But why not use the DVI converter again?" Because the computer I just ordered has a DVI-D port, while the connecter is a DVI-A male. At first I attempted to bend back / break out the four pins (as I have no use for this DVI adpater since I'm no longer using the old desktop), only to learn that, at a closer look, the long "pin" or what not is longer than a DVI-D pin is.

So now what I want to know is, before I order a new DVI-D or DVI-I adapter, is there a way to switch the default output to (preferably) VGA, or (if that doesn't work,) HDMI, on my computer? Searching here and on Google merely yielded people asking about faulty setups. I know I don't have a faulty setup, and my chords are all working.

Thanks